# A hot key <hot-key-name> was detected in our Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have been facing a hot key issue in our Dataflow pipeline (`streaming` pipeline, `batch` load into BigQuery -- we are using batch for a cost-effective purpose):

We are ingesting data to according tables based on their decoder value. For example, data with `http` decoder are going to `http` table, data with `ssl` decoder are going to `ssl` table.

So the BigQuery ingestion is using dynamic destinations.

The key is the destination table spec for the data.

An example error log:

```
A hot key 
'key: tableSpec: ace-prod-300923:ml_dataset_us_central1.ssl tableDescription: Table for ssl shard: 1' 
was detected in step 
'insertTableRowsToBigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionsReshuffle/GroupByKey/ReadStream' with age of '1116.266s'. 
This is a symptom of key distribution being skewed. 
To fix, please inspect your data and pipeline to ensure that elements are evenly distributed across your key space.
```

Error is detected in this step: `'insertTableRowsToBigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionsReshuffle/GroupByKey/ReadStream'`

The hot key issue is because of the nature of data, some decoder data has disproportionately many values. And our pipeline is a streaming pipeline.

We have read the [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#hot-key-detected) provided by Google but still not sure how to fix it.

1. Dataflow shuffle. Our project is already using streaming engine
2. Rekey. Doesn't seem to apply to our case, as the key is the destination table spec. To make the ingestion work, the key has to match the existing table spec in bigquery.
3. `Combine.PerKey.withHotKeyFanout()`.  I don't know how to apply this. Because the key is generated in this step: `insertTableRowsToBigQuery`. This step, we are using BigQueryIO to write to BigQuery. The key is coming from dynamically generate BigQuery table names based on the current window or the current value. [Sharding BigQuery output tables](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#:%7E:text=Sharding%20BigQuery%20output%20tables)

Attached the code where the hot key is detected:

```java
toBq.apply("insertTableRowsToBigQuery",
    BigQueryIO
            .<DataIntoBQ>write()
            .to((ValueInSingleWindow<DataIntoBQ> dataIntoBQ) -> {
                        try {
                            String decoder = dataIntoBQ.getValue().getDecoder(); // getter function
        
                            String destination = String.format("%s:%s.%s",
                                        PROJECT_ID, DATASET, decoder);
                            if (!listOfProtocols.contains(decoder)) {
                                LOG.error("wrong bigquery table decoder destination: " + decoder);
                            }
                            return new TableDestination(
                                        destination, // Table spec
                                        "Table for " + decoder // Table description
                            );
                    
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            LOG.error("insertTableRowsToBigQuery error", e);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
            )
            .withFormatFunction(
                    (DataIntoBQ elem) ->
                            new DataIntoBQ().toTableRow(elem)
            )
            .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
            .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardMinutes(3))
            .withAutoSharding()
            .withCustomGcsTempLocation(ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(options.getGcpTempLocation()))
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still try the rekey strategy. For example, you can apply a transformation before the `apply("insertTableRowsToBigQuery")` such that:

elements with the key "http" -> "randomVal_http" whereas randomVal is a value in a specific range (say from 0 to 10) the width of range depends on how many splits you want your elements with key http to be split into. For example, if you have 10 million elements with key "http", and you want to make sure they are split in 10 groups, each with approx. 10 elements you can generate uniform rand nrs between 0 and 9.

the same mapping you can apply to elements that belong to hot keys, element with non-hot keys don't need to be rekeyed.

Now, in your "insertTableRowsToBigQuery", you know how to go from a key like "someVal_http" to "http" - split the string.

That should help.

Regarding the `Combine.PerKey.withHotKeyFanout()` I am not sure how to do this for IO Transforms. If it was some intermediate transform, I could have helpled